# Question about a conjugate of an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

While reading a book, I came across,

$$
{\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)dx} = \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{f(-x)}dx=\overline{\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx}
$$
with the assumption that $g(-x)=\overline{f(x)}$.

Can some somebody explain, how this happens?

Comment: If $g(-x) = \overline{f(x)}$, then $g(x) = g(-(-x)) = \overline{f(-x)}$.

Comment: Which equality is confusing?  mrf addressed the first, do you understand what's going on now?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you to both.With mrf kind help now I understand the left hand equality but still confused about the right side equality.

Comment: I know that $
\int_{\mathbb R} \overline{f(x)}dx=\overline{\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx} 
$ but confused about $
\int_{\mathbb R} \overline{f(-x)}dx=\overline{\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx} 
$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last equality occurs because if $f(x)$ is a complex valued function, we can write it as the sum of two functions and that integrals and conjugating are linear operations. Letting $r(x) = \mathcal{Re}(f(x))$ and $c(x) = \mathcal{Im}(f(x))$  we have $f(x) = r(x) + ic(x)$ and then $\overline{f(-x)} = r(-x) - ic(-x)$. Now using linearity we get

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\overline{f(-x)}dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}r(-x) - ic(-x)dx\\
 &=\int_{\mathbb{R}} r(-x)dx - i\int_{\mathbb{R}}c(-x)dx \tag{*}\label{*}
\end{align}

As all of the integrals on the right-hand side of (*) are just over the region $\mathbb{R}$ we can simply change the sign of the variable without affecting the integral (If $T(x) = -x$, $|\det(T)| = 1$), ie. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} r(-x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}r(x)dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}c(-x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}c(x)dx$.
Then finally we we can just re-write (*) as another complex conjugate and then apply the linearity of the integral in reverse, as so:

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\overline{f(-x)}dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} r(x)dx - i\int_{\mathbb{R}}c(x)dx\\
 &= \overline{\int_{\mathbb{R}} r(x)dx + i\int_{\mathbb{R}}c(x)dx}\\
 &= \overline{\int_{\mathbb{R}} r(x) + ic(x)dx}\\
 &= \overline{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)}.
\end{align}